# How to handle ContextMenuStrip property, exspecially border color

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

How to handle `ContextMenuStrip` property, especially border-color???

Any method in C# OR Any way by using Windows API (DllImport)?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the border color of the menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom Color table and change Renderer property:

```
 public class MenuColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public MenuColorTable()
    {
        UseSystemColors = false;
    }
    public override Color MenuBorder
    {
        get { return Color.Fuchsia; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return Color.DarkViolet; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.Cornsilk; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.LawnGreen; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.MediumSeaGreen; }
    }
    public override Color MenuStripGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.AliceBlue; }
    }
    public override Color MenuStripGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.DodgerBlue; }
    }
}
```

Changing `Renderer`:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MenuColorTable());
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result of menu]

Comment: OMG!! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Don't forget to precede setting the renderer with contextMenuStrip1.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional;